# How to notify user if connection fails to BLE device in Android?

Tags: android, callback, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

How do I notify users if the device they are trying to connect to does not connect, besides waiting and testing for a connection.  There does not seem to be any callback for a failed connection after trying connectGatt().
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method:  connGATT() has 3 parameters. The third one is a callback:

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

if you want to know the connection is success or not, you should add override the method:

```
@Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                int newState)
```

Here is the link.https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

The whole callback looks like this:

```
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        // New services discovered
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        // Result of a characteristic read operation
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }
     ...
    };
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do have the callback set up, but there is no state change for 'failed to connect'.  Bluetooth classic has 'mmSocket.connect()', and it throws an exception if connection does not happen.  I don't know how to tell if the connection failed except by polling the device, or having a timeout on the 'State_Connected' flag.  Is there something I am missing?  Thank you.

Comment: See you have "status" and "newStatus" right? If "status" !=GATT_SUCCESS, it means the gatt connection failed, If "status" == GATT_SUCCESS && "newState" == STATE_CONNECTED, it means the connection success and get a Peripheral connected.

Comment: If I try to connect and the device is not available, onConnectionStateChange does not fire at all, so I cannot check the status.